# Extending an existing control for MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, mvvm, dependency-properties

I am tring to extend an existing microsoft control called the PivotViewer.

This control has an existing property that I want to expose to my ViewModel.

```
public ICollection<string> InScopeItemIds { get; }
```

I have created an inherited class called CustomPivotViewer and I want to create a Dependency Property that I can bind to that will expose the values held in InScopeItemIds in the base class.

I have spent a fair while reading up about DependencyPropertys and am becomming quite disheartened.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

I realized misunderstandings and here is a new version (in the context of the original question):

So, you can use the property you need for the binding, with following circumstances having in mind:

- as this property is read-only, you will not be able to use it for 2-way binding.
- as far as the containing type does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, your target control used to display the data will not be notified about the changes to the property value.
- as far as the returned by this property value does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged (one example is ObservableCollection<T>), the changes to the collection will not be affected on the target control which is used to display it.

Comment: The property in the question doesn't have a setter.

Comment: That means the value gets changed using some class specific inner code which you cannot alter, right? In that case you cannot see the changes on your target control when the property changes.

Comment: @Tengiz, remind me, one way binding is set and not get, correct?

Comment: One way binding means the source property gets shown on the target control. So you can show it but you cannot alter it from the target control. For simplicity: target can be a textbox, and source can be your class. Again, if the class does not implement the INOtifyPropertyChanged, then the control will not update its value when the class value changes.

Comment: You **can** have two-way DataBinding with **any** property that has **both** a setter and a getter. `DependencyProperty` is when you want to enable the property *itself* to be *Bindable* (see my reply)

Comment: And why would you use 2 way binding without having a need to project control changes to the source object back?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a `DependencyProperty` is you want **it** to be bindable, meaning: if you want to have, for example, a `MyBindableProperty` property in your control, with which you want to be able to do:

```
MyBindableProperty={Binding SomeProperty}
```

if, however, you want **other `DependencyProperties`** to bind **to it**, any property (either a `DependencyProperty` or a normal one) can be used.

I'm not sure what you really need, maybe you can clarify more, but if it's the first scenario that you want to implement, you can do it as follows:

- create a `DependencyProperty`, let's call it `BindableInScopeItemIds`, like so:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// BindableInScopeItemIds Dependency Property
  /// </summary>
  public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableInScopeItemIdsProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("BindableInScopeItemIds", typeof(ICollection<string>), typeof(CustomPivotViewer),
          new PropertyMetadata(null,
              new PropertyChangedCallback(OnBindableInScopeItemIdsChanged)));

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets the BindableInScopeItemIds property. This dependency property 
  /// indicates ....
  /// </summary>
  public ICollection<string> BindableInScopeItemIds
  {
      get { return (ICollection<string>)GetValue(BindableInScopeItemIdsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(BindableInScopeItemIdsProperty, value); }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Handles changes to the BindableInScopeItemIds property.
  /// </summary>
  private static void OnBindableInScopeItemIdsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      var target = (CustomPivotViewer)d;
      ICollection<string> oldBindableInScopeItemIds = (ICollection<string>)e.OldValue;
      ICollection<string> newBindableInScopeItemIds = target.BindableInScopeItemIds;
      target.OnBindableInScopeItemIdsChanged(oldBindableInScopeItemIds, newBindableInScopeItemIds);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Provides derived classes an opportunity to handle changes to the BindableInScopeItemIds property.
  /// </summary>
  protected virtual void OnBindableInScopeItemIdsChanged(ICollection<string> oldBindableInScopeItemIds, ICollection<string> newBindableInScopeItemIds)
  {
  }
  ```
- in the `OnBindableInScopeItemIdsChanged`, you can update the inner collection (`InScopeItemIds`)

remember that the property you want to expose is *read-only* (it has no "setter"), so you might need to update it as so:

```
protected virtual void OnBindableInScopeItemIdsChanged(ICollection<string> oldBindableInScopeItemIds, ICollection<string> newBindableInScopeItemIds)
{
    InScopeItemIds.Clear();
    foreach (var itemId in newBindableInScopeItemIds)
    {
        InScopeItemIds.Add(itemId);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think using a 2 way binding is already a sign that he wants to have a property binded. no?

Comment: @Tengiz: not really. You can have a `Name` (normal) property that you bind to a the `Text` (Dependency) property of a `TextBlock` with a 2-way mode. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: And you think this makes sense? Any changes to this textblock will not affect the name property anyway, so this TwoWay behaves like OneWay, exactly. no?

Comment: yes, it does affect it. And even though I was sure about it, I tried it again anyway, and it works just fine!

Comment: So you have a class which has a non-dependency, read-only property which is affected by the control binding? I don't believe in this :-) but I get it, you mean class property is not read-only. and what about changes to the property which you want to see on the textblock?

Comment: @Tengiz: I didn't say anything about a "read-only" property! glad that cleared out :) for the changes to a property to be reflected to the binded DependencyProperty (of the `TextBlock` for example), you need to implement change notification, through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and rase the `PropertyChanged`event whenever the property is set :)